# .htaccess - redirect from old domain to new and force HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble getting these redirects to work under all conditions. I'm hoping I can fix it with .htaccess but there may be something mucked up with the way I'd previously tried to force redirects through my host's control panel.

Anyway, olddomain.com/whatever, with http:// or https:// and with or without www should permanently redirect to https://www.newdomain.com/whatever.

At one point I had everything except https://olddomain.com redirecting properly. Now I've broken it and I'm just getting the too many redirects error.

I believe both domains have a Let's Encrypt certificate attached to them. The old domain doesn't need to be secured if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://serverfault.com/a/728957, you can use this snippet to help redirect users to a `https://www` of the site.

```
RewriteEngine On
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Looks like that almost gets me there. After your snippet I've got this:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

That seems to finish the task. Thanks!